# ARCore – 3d object rendered in front of my face

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I have a glass model that's rendered with Augmented Faces API. This works correctly when my face is in front. But when my face in half-profile the model is renderer on my face.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: GLES20.glDepthMask(true); works for me, make sure there's no GLES20.glDepthMask(false); anywhere else in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Augmented Faces API` can be run with its new companion – `Depth API` that is a part of ARCore 1.18. Depth API gives ARCore developers `Occlusion` feature for selfie front camera or for rear camera working with `iToF` laser sensor. For this you need a device that supports Depth API (look at the [last column of the list](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) of ARCore supported devices).

However, due to sensors' and technologies' imperfectness, sometimes artifacts are possible. That's why temples of glasses are composited in front of your face, not behind it. So occlusion is not working properly even Depth API is turned on. At the moment you can't ged rid of these nasty artifacts.

Comment: thanks , sorry my reputation less for reputation and can not click (this answer is useful).. if possible more explain or send document for depth api selfi camera

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/overview

Answer (score 0):

it looks like occlusion Material bug in sceneform deprecated sdk
(with filament render inside). https://github.com/google/filament/issues/1994

Comment: Please read [answer]. Currently your answer contains a brief attempt to answer, and a much longer question. You should [edit] your answer to remove the question, then ask it as your own question.